# How to set custom layout when using nuxt-property-decorator?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

### Summery

I want to set different header component to specific page.

```
layout
  ├ default.vue // <- common header
  └ custom.vue // <- special header for spesific page
```

I want to know how to set different layout when useing nuxt-property-decorator.
https://github.com/nuxt-community/nuxt-property-decorator

```
"nuxt": "^2.15.7",
"nuxt-property-decorator": "^2.9.1",
```

### Some code

#### Case1

```
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue,} from 'nuxt-property-decorator'

@Component
export default class Component extends Vue {
  layout () { // <- error on layout
    return 'custom'
  }
}
```

It returns following error

```
Duplicate function implementation.Vetur(2393)
```

#### Case 2

```
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'nuxt-property-decorator'

@Component({
  layout: 'custom' // <- error on layout: 'custom'
})
export default class Component extends Vue {
}
```

It returns following error

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(options: ComponentOptions<Vue, DefaultData<Vue>, DefaultMethods<Vue>, DefaultComputed, PropsDefinition<DefaultProps>, DefaultProps> & ThisType<...>): <VC extends VueClass<...>>(target: VC) => VC', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ layout: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentOptions<Vue, DefaultData<Vue>, DefaultMethods<Vue>, DefaultComputed, PropsDefinition<DefaultProps>, DefaultProps> & ThisType<...>'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'layout' does not exist in type 'ComponentOptions<Vue, DefaultData<Vue>, DefaultMethods<Vue>, DefaultComputed, PropsDefinition<DefaultProps>, DefaultProps> & ThisType<...>'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(target: VueClass<Vue>): VueClass<Vue>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ layout: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'VueClass<Vue>'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'layout' does not exist in type 'VueClass<Vue>'.Vetur(2769)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it's reqired to set layout on `pages`, not `components`.

```
├ components
│  └ index.vue // <- not here
└ pages 
   └ index.vue // <- here
```

It worked on pages/index.vue

```
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'nuxt-property-decorator'

@Component({
  layout: 'custom',
})
export default class Page extends Vue {

}
</script>
```